# How to create a block with taxonomy terms and their corresponding nodes?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

This is what I want to achieve in views:

Taxonomy vocabular "Categories":

Term 1 -> 3 node titles;

Term 2 -> 3 node titles;

Term 3 -> 3 node titles;

Comment: I assume you are trying to put all of this in a single block?  It would be rather easy with 3 separate blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to use [views_field_view](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module. In you views :

1. Create a view of Taxonomy type
2. Add a filter of Taxonomy Vocabulary = Categories
3. Add filed Term: tid (exclude) and Term: Name
4. Add Global View field pass argument tid (Another view in which contextual filter of tid is added and 3 items are displayed in views configuration)

Done.